# What does it mean for a surface to be null homologous?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, surfaces

The question is as stated in the title. What does it mean for a surface to be null homologous? I know that a $p$ cycle of a complex is homologous to $0$ (which I assume is the same as being null homologous) if it the boundary of a $p+1$ chain. But still I cannot figure out what exactly is meant by being null homologous? Any explanation or if you could point me towards a good reference I would much appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe greenberg and harper,  munkres or even spanier's book.  Spanier was quite gifted.

Comment: I seem to remember it has to do with n-connectedness.  But it's been a long time. ..

Answer (score 3):

It means that its fundamental class is a boundary for the singular homology.

Comment: Is there an alternate definition? I have never studied fundamental classes

Comment: Or heard of fundamental classes

Comment: Oh wait I guess I have let me think about this

Comment: take a triangulation of the surface and add the 2-simplex you obtain the fundamental class,

Comment: Could you possible give an example?